# How to check if a column has no value (empty) in all rows in data table in c#

Tags: c#

I had pushed the excel file into my data table. The columns empty in excel were left empty in data table.

I guess they are not treated as null.

Can anyone help how to check for empty rows in some column in a data table .

```
//successfully loaded excel into datatable
OleDbDataReader dr= oledbCommand. ExecuteReader ();
dataTable. Load (dr);
```

Problem- empty cells in columns remained empty in data table also.

Doubt- Are these empty values in datatable are null??

If not how to check whether `dataTable.Rows [1][1]` is empty or not?

Please help!

Comment: show us your code please

Answer (score 2):

You can use linq :

```
bool IsColumnEmpty  =  dt.AsEnumerable().All(dr=>string.IsNullOrEmpty( dr["name"]+""));
```

Test :

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("myTable");
dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof (int));
dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof (string));
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
row["id"] = 1;
//row["name"] = "";
dt.Rows.Add(row);
row = dt.NewRow();
row["id"] = 0;
//row["name"] = "zzz";
dt.Rows.Add(row);
row = dt.NewRow();
row["id"] = 2;
//row["name"] = "222";
dt.Rows.Add(row);
dt.Dump();

bool IsColumnEmpty=  dt.AsEnumerable().All(dr=>string.IsNullOrEmpty( dr["name"]+""));
Console.WriteLine (IsColumnEmpty);
```

Result :

[image]

Let's remove `//` from `//row["name"] = "222";`

Result :

[image]

Comment: My datatable shows no value in some columns in any row when I debug and magnify it. I want to write some check condition to it. Something like - if(datatable.rows [][] is not empty)